# Area under the difference between two functions assuming a bounded hessian

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ be functions defined over $\mathbb{R}$, where we assume the following:

- $f''(x) < h''(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, where $f''$ and $h''$  denote the second derivatives.
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx = 1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x) \,dx = 1$.
- $f(x),h(x) \ge 0$.

I want to show that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$ < $\int_{a}^{b} h(x) \,dx$, is this possible?

Comment: $f$ and $h$ are supposed to be 2-times differentiables on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @SacAndSac Yes they are!

Comment: What have you tried so far? No efforts by your side, no efforts from this side! ... please, improve your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a counterexample:
Take
$$
f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-(x-1)^2), \quad h(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-x^2)
$$
and $[a, b] = \left[\frac{3}{4}, 1 \right]$. It is easy to show that $f''(x) < h''(x)$, since one is negative there and one is not.

Now observe that $f(x) > h(x)$ on $\left[\frac{3}{4}, 1 \right]$ since
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-(x-1)^2) > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-x^2) \iff 
$$
$$
\exp(-x^2+2x-1) > \exp(-x^2) \iff
$$
$$
\exp(2x-1) > 1
$$
is clearly true if $x \in \left[\frac{3}{4}, 1 \right]$. So $\int_\frac{3}{4}^1 f ~\mathrm{d}x > \int^1_\frac{3}{4} h~\mathrm{d}x$.

Both functions clearly have integral $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
[[image: <span class=]$f$ and $h$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW0Pk.png)

[[image: <span class=]$f''$ and $h''$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AOZg.png)